# SQLite: Select minimum value in a range from n to n-y

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have a list of orders identified by an id and a customer. I need to know the id of the order of index n-9 starting from the order of index n placed by that customer.

For example:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders 
WHERE CustomerID = "1808317576" AND OrderID < 29 
ORDER BY OrderID DESC LIMIT 9
```

The query above returns these records:

| OrderID |
| --- |
| 28 |
| 26 |
| 23 |
| 20 |
| 19 |
| 18 |
| 17 |
| 16 |
| 13 |

To solve my problem I tried to do:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders 
WHERE CustomerID = "1808317576" AND OrderID < 29 
ORDER BY OrderID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I would need:

| OrderID |
| --- |
| 13 |

But it returns this:

| OrderID |
| --- |
| 28 |

I then tried to remove the `DESC` from the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders 
WHERE CustomerID = "1808317576" AND OrderID < 29 
ORDER BY OrderID LIMIT 1
```

But it returns this:

| OrderID |
| --- |
| 1 |

**How can I get 13?!**

Comment: SQLite supports window functions. That might be a good place to start: https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: @crcvd there is no need for window functions for such a simple requirement. In fact it would be much worse for performance to use ROW_NUMBER here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `OFFSET 8` to skip the first 8 rows returned and set `LIMIT 1`:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders 
WHERE CustomerID = '1808317576' AND OrderID < 29 
ORDER BY OrderID DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 8
```

Or simpler:

```
SELECT OrderID 
FROM Orders 
WHERE CustomerID = '1808317576' AND OrderID < 29 
ORDER BY OrderID DESC 
LIMIT 8,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just subquery your current query and order in the opposite (ascending) direction, with a limit of 1:

```sql
SELECT OrderID
FROM
(
    SELECT OrderID
    FROM Orders
    WHERE CustomerID = '1808317576' AND OrderID < 29
    ORDER BY OrderID DESC
    LIMIT 9
) t
ORDER BY OrderID
LIMIT 1;
```